# Action Filter on Pie Map Chart

Tags: tableau-api

I have a map and a table which looks something like this.

[image]

Following action filter has been applied on dashboard.

[image]

But as described in the first image, I can only select On ground or In transit Inventory for a particular dealer code.I want to make sure that the entire dealer code is selected and both the inventory types are shown in the table below.

How can this be achieved. I think this can be done by dual axis map, but not sure how.
I also want to make sure that when i hover over the dealer code, total inventory is shown in the tooltip instead of On ground and In transit as separate.

Current Tooltip Screenshot :

[image]

Workbook Link [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U20pzgQiTi7JuPNAtuvuhzoODTHVkhgD):

Answer (score 0):

One option is create a Donut chart where if you select the middle part then entire dealer code is selected and if you select the outer part then either `In Transit` of `OnGround` is selected.

Donut chart design:

One pie chart (Which you already have) has Intransit and On ground

Create one more pie chart for dealer code

Now create dual axis adjust the pie chart that dealer code pie chart will be small compared to first one and appears at middle of the dual axis

Now when you click middle circle, Write action filter to show both InTransit and Onground and if you click outer circle then create one more action filter for either of the data.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Siva, the donut chart is a great idea to give different details on different granularities, however it would be difficult to convince the client for this. But I found a turnaround that i would like to share. If i go to action filters and then use selected fields in target filters, there i can choose dealer code. This will ensure that when i click any inventory type, i get the whole data

Comment: Im struggling with the tooltip though, where I want to show the total inventory(irrespective of In transit or On Ground)
I tried to use Fixed LOD, but that will not change my values when i filter it down using some dimensions

MY LoD : { fixed  [dealer code] : countd(serail number) }

Comment: When you use fixed data doesn't change, try using Include or Exclude instead of Fixed

Comment: What would include filter look like here?

Comment: Also for the donut chart that you suggested, how would i add an action to the inner circle? I would like to propose this to the users

Comment: @KapilLehar sorry for late reply...Do to the dashboard filters and edit actions there select fields corresponding to inner and outer circles, This should work